# Unity IAP for IOS -- No App Receipt found

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, app-store, unity-game-engine

I am trying set up some in-app purchases through Unity IAP for iOS devices. Registering the various product IDs, the initialization process seems to have passed successfully. However, when I tried to make a purchase using an iPad connected to a Mac, I received an error message on XCode saying:

```
UnityIAP: No App Receipt found
```

The purchase failed. The reason given for the error was: Unknown.

On the Unity editor, the purchase did go through without any problem.

So what could be the reason? What is an App Receipt?

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?

Comment: Yes. See my answer below... Did you encounter the same issue? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hired a freelancer to fix the issue. He asked me to test the system with a test user's account, and it succeeded. Apparently, for the IAP to work, all I needed to do was to release and publish the game in the Apple's App Store, and download the app from the App Store directly!

It is also worthwhile mentioning that we need to fill in the forms at Agreements, Tax, and Banking. Otherwise the initialisation process won't even pass.

Comment: Ah ok. So downloading via Test Flight would make sense I guess. I assumed that the app would get linked up to xcode by the app bundle id but perhaps not. I shall give that a try. Many Thanks :D